# Checking Row by Row in a report

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-design, report

With reference to this question,

[Changing Row Colour according to condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438469/changing-row-colour-according-to-condition)

I got familiar with Conditional formatting. However I still face this problem.

I am using this code to convert time into Time in Minutes.

```
Dim TestString As String

TestString = Me.Duration

Dim TestArray() As String

TestArray = Split(TestString, ":")

Dim Hours As String
Dim Minutes As String
Dim Seconds As String

Dim HoursMinutes As Integer
Dim MinutesMinutes As Integer
Dim SecondsMinutes As Integer

Hours = TestArray(0)
Minutes = TestArray(1)
Seconds = TestArray(2)

HoursMinutes = CInt(TestArray(0)) * 60
MinutesMinutes = CInt(TestArray(1))
SecondsMinutes = CInt(TestArray(2)) / 60

Dim TimeInMinutes As Integer

TimeInMinutes = HoursMinutes + MinutesMinutes + SecondsMinutes

Me.Duration = TimeInMinutes
```

However, for some reason this is not working.

Have you any ideas how can I do this for seperate rows?

Thanks in advance

ADD:

I tried creating a field for Minutes, the problem is that they will get all the same number.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438469/changing-row-colour-according-to-condition (With reference to this question)

Comment: I tried creating a field for Minutes, the problem is that they will get all the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below code has a String variable called *`dateTime`* which stores the current date and time in this format: *`27/08/2013 10:55:52`*

The *`dateTime`* String is getting split into a Variant *`arr`* array

`Split(dateTime, Chr(32))(1)` returns the time `10:55:52` part of the *`dateTime`* variable

then `Split(Split(dateTime, Chr(32))(1), ":")` splits the time into 3 numbers using `:` *(colon)* as delimiter

So you end up with with `arr` holding  # of hrs, # of minutes, # of seconds.

The `CLng((arr(0) * 60) + arr(1) + (arr(2) / 60))` returns an Integer/Long representation of the calculated time value

Stick the below sub in a fresh module and run it

```
Sub Convert()

    Dim dateTime As String
    dateTime = now

    Dim arr
    arr = Split(Split(dateTime, Chr(32))(1), ":")

    MsgBox "The time " & Split(dateTime, Chr(32))(1) & vbCrLf & _
        " as Integer is equal to " & CLng((arr(0) * 60) + arr(1) + (arr(2) / 60))

End Sub
```

Comment: I have done that! Thanks, owever I tried insertting a similar altered code into Detail_Paint function.

My problm arises as conditional formatting then refreshes as I scroll down the report..